# Python coding, issue with the while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am beginning in Python and cannot seemed to find the bug in my script ..

I have the following Python script but the random function does not work the way I want it to do.. Indeed, I would like either "head" or "tail" to be selected by the computer (and not just only either all heads or all tails):

```
print("\n\tWelcome to the 'Flip a coin' program")

import random

input("\nPress the enter key to start playing!")

flip_coin=random.randint(1,2)

heads=0
tails=0
rolls=int(input("\nPlease, tell the computer how many rolls you want to do? "))
essai=0

while essai<rolls:
    essai+=1
    if flip_coin==1:
        heads+=1
        print("You've got a head")
    else:
        tails+=1
        print("You've got a tail")

print("\n\tThe job is done..")
print("\n\tYou have a total of", heads,"heads and", tails,"tails")
```

Results:

```
Welcome to the 'Flip a coin' program

Press the enter key to start playing!

Please, tell the computer how many rolls you want to do? 10
You've got a head
You've got a head
You've got a head
You've got a head
You've got a head
You've got a head
You've got a head
You've got a head
You've got a head
You've got a head

    The job is done..

    You have a total of 10 heads and 0 tails
```

Do you know what should I modify, please ?

Thank you for your much appreciated help!

Comment: You need to assign a new random number to `flip_coin` inside your loop if you want the loop to do something different on each iteration.  Each time you call `randint` it's like flipping a coin -- what happens if you flip a coin once and then count it ten times?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and your explanation! I just added the line : flip_coin=random.randint(1,2) within the while loop and it worked as expected..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasoning is that `random.randint` value is static for scope its defined in. In this case, being defined in the *global* scope, so it is static for the entire program.

It cannot be change unless the value is taken out and then replaced (ousted if you will).

Take for instance, a silly example:

```py
>>> import random
>>> flip_coin=random.randint(1,2)
>>> captured=flip_coin
>>> captured
1
>>> for i in range(1, int(1e20)):
...     if flip_coin != captured:
...        print('HUH!')
```

This will receive no output in the console.

Thusly, value assigned to `flip_coin` variable must be change somehow - for ex. within a loop as suggested.

Here is a larger example:

```py
>>> import random
>>> flip_coin=random.randint(1,2)
>>> captured=flip_coin
>>> for i in range(1, int(1e3+7+2)):
...   flip_coin=random.randint(1,2)
...   if flip_coin != captured:
...     print('It CHANGED!')
...   else:
...     print('Its the SAME!')
...   captured=flip_coin
...
```

Output - yours will likely be *different*:

```
Its the SAME!
It CHANGED!
It CHANGED!
Its the SAME!
Its the SAME!
It CHANGED!
It CHANGED!
It CHANGED!
It CHANGED!
It CHANGED!
Its the SAME!
...
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply! I didn't think of using the "for" loop..

Answer (score 0):

Now you calculate the value of `flip_coin` just once, at 7-th line. You can use a lambda function to get a new value every time when you call it:

```
print("\n\tWelcome to the 'Flip a coin' program")

import random

input("\nPress the enter key to start playing!")

flip_coin = lambda: random.randint(1,2)

heads=0
tails=0
rolls=int(input("\nPlease, tell the computer how many rolls you want to do? "))
essai=0

while essai<rolls:
    essai+=1
    if flip_coin() == 1:
        heads+=1
        print("You've got a head")
    else:
        tails+=1
        print("You've got a tail")

print("\n\tThe job is done..")
print("\n\tYou have a total of", heads,"heads and", tails,"tails")
```

Alternatively you can calculate a new value at line 17 like this:

```
if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
    heads+=1
    print("You've got a head")
else:
    tails+=1
    print("You've got a tail")
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! Now I realize the multiple ways of coding with similar outputs